# Angular-strap data-trigger='focus' not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-strap

the `data-trigger` focus is not working for me ...

```
<span data-content='foo' data-html='true' data-placement='top' data-container='body' data-trigger='focus' bs-popover>
```

Nothing is actually happening when I am clicking on this element. If I remove `data-trigger='focus'` and set it to `hover` or `click`, it does work.

I am using angularjs. 1.2.18 and angular-strap : 2.2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `tabindex` attribute to make a `<span>` focus-able. This also applies for `<div>` and `<table>` elements.

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element
>   can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to
>   sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position. It can
>   takes several values:
>
> - a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;
> - 0 means that the element should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but its relative order is defined by
>     the platform convention;
> - a positive value which means should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation; its relative order is defined by the
>     value of the attribute: the sequential follow the increasing number of
>     the tabindex. If several elements share the same tabindex, their
>     relative order follows their relative position in the

Observe the following change to your markup...

```
<span data-content='foo' 
    data-html='true' 
    data-placement='top' 
    data-container='body' 
    data-trigger='focus' 
    bs-popover
    tabindex='0'>
```

see [MDN tabindex source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PDUQKCnTCN0yYLyfJ8uv?p=preview) - stripped demo from the docs with `tabindex`

Comment: this did not solve my problem and what I experience is only with the first time my typeahead input is focused. second time and the rest works fine. meaning it only works if the element is focused, loses focus and then is focused again.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. This is for a popover not a typeahead

Comment: True, true... I thought it was a Angular-strap data-trigger='focus' not working question.